# CustomPaint inside custom button flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a custom button that I plan to reuse over and over again.

1. How can I put a CustomPainter into CustomButtom, with the condition that it also changes its internal state?

```
class CustomButton extends StatelessWidget {
  CustomButton({this.icon, this.text, this.onPressed});

  final Icon icon;
  final Text text;
  final Function onPressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RawMaterialButton(
      onPressed: onPressed,
      elevation: 2.0,
      fillColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 90,
        height: 90,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            icon,
            text,
            Container(
              height: 15,
              width: 70,
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red,
                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(Radius.elliptical(45, 10)),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      shape: CircleBorder(),
    );
  }
}
```

2. How can I implement a smile animation that should not be a rotation, but a transition from one state to another?
   Smooth redrawing of the CustomPaint part when the button is pressed

```
class SmileyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final radius = 100.0;
    final center = Offset(150, 120);
    // Body
    final paint = Paint()..color = Colors.yellow;
    canvas.drawCircle(center, radius, paint);
    // Eyes
    canvas.drawOval(
        Rect.fromCenter(
            center: Offset(center.dx + radius / 3, center.dy - radius / 3),
            width: 25,
            height: 60),
        Paint());
    canvas.drawOval(
        Rect.fromCenter(
            center: Offset(center.dx - radius / 3, center.dy - radius / 3),
            width: 25,
            height: 60),
        Paint());
    final paintMouth =  Paint()
      ..color = Colors.black
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 10;

    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(200, 150);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(150, 200, 100, 150);
    path.moveTo(200, 150);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(150, 220, 100, 150);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paintMouth);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```